# Could not load file or assembly and one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, umbraco

> Could not load file or assembly 'interfaces, Version=1.0.5948.18141, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have no idea what is causing this or how I could debug it to find the cause.

- Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase.StartApplication(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
- Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +34

Can't find any reference anywhere which goes against 1.2.0.0 in any of my projects.

Any ideas how I should go about solving this?

I would also appreciate tips on how to debug problems like this in general.

Comment: First thing I check would be the bin folder where your code is running to see if the 'missing' assembly is there or not. If the file does exist, check the version is correct.

Comment: Which version of Umbraco are you using? Which packages are installed?

Comment: Can you show your csproj file? Maybe there are some problems. Or you can read this article, there are some solutions, which may help you:https://chiragrupani.medium.com/how-to-resolve-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-and-why-this-cf8d48d788eb

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces is part of the Umbraco.Cms.Core package.  Looking at another example:

```
<Reference Include="interfaces, Version=1.0.5948.18141, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\UmbracoCms.Core.7.4.3\lib\interfaces.dll</HintPath>
```

Look in you UmbracoCms.Core.x.x.x\lib\ folder in your packages folder to see if it's there.  If not re-install/force get from Nuget and good luck!